# Different WebAPiConfig for different Controllers

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I am developing a REST API developed in ASP.NET Web API 2. I have the following WebAPiConfig in App_Start folder.

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API configuration and services
        SystemDiagnosticsTraceWriter traceWriter = config.EnableSystemDiagnosticsTracing();
        traceWriter.IsVerbose = true;
        traceWriter.MinimumLevel = TraceLevel.Debug;
        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{docType}/{id}",
            defaults: new { docType = RouteParameter.Optional, id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
        config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings { NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore };
    }
}
```

We have a lot of entities with a number of properties, So what I do is using following line of code in configuration to ignore all the **`NULL`** values.

> config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings { NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore };

It works fine with our AngularJS front-end. Recently we are developing an Android app for a segment of our product. For that we have made a separate **Controller**, that is only called from Android app.

Due to some reason, I need to send JSON with full properties(without ignoring NULL) to the app.

The problem is that if, I omit the above mentioned configuration, it will return full properties (with NULL for web front-end). What I am looking for is that, is there anything like multiple WebApiConfiguration for different controllers and we just use them like attributes on top of class.

I have searched a lot but what I find is only multiple routing. I want different configuration for different controller.

Comment: Not the nicest way, but there's a backup option to return 
`ApiController.Json(object, JsonSerializerSettings)` (`JsonResult<T>`). Needs to be applied to every action though.

Comment: thats the problem @Caramiriel, there are hundreds of actions. Can't apply on every one.